# x86 assembly: how do I use a semicolon within a string constant?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I have some x86 assembly code, compiling under MASM32 6.14.8444 (to be precise), and there is one line of code that is causing me some problems:

```
semicolon equ ";"
```

As you can see, I'm simply trying to assign the text ";" to a variable named 'semicolon', but I get this error:

```
error A2046: missing single or double quotation mark in string
```

I'm guessing this is because assembly takes the semicolon to be the start of a comment. In this case, how can I escape the semicolon in my string constant?

Comment: Sounds like a poor assembler; most (e.g. NASM) do allow the comment character inside quotes, like `';'` to work as a numeric literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This compiles

```
semicolon equ 0x3b
```